# Odd symbols in https responce

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I did asked that question last week but nobody answered me.

I came across a strange problem whilst using the jQuery AJAX functionality. Strange symbols are appearing at the beginning of the response from the server:

Here is a screenshot.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfEX9.png]

```
$.post('/ajax/', {email : $('#email').val(), language : $('#lng').val()}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
});
```

I Googled a lot but couldn't find any similar issues. What could be the problem ?

Comment: In that case you should edit your previous question to add more details. Editing bumps your question to the top of the active questions feed, and lots of new people get to see it.

Comment: Are you sure your response is proper 'UTF-8'?

Comment: @Pushpesh Not the issue.  Those are clearly characters from another language..  I forget which, but I know they're either one of two.  Anyway, point being, this user appears to be victim of malware injections.

Comment: I have this line of code header('Content-Type: text/html charset=utf-8'); in my php file
@Pushpesh this happens only in internet explorer and opera. On chrome safari and firefox it works.